# How to use Terminal.app for an xterm session

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app, xterm

I am on Mac OS X 10.8. When I open Terminal.app and connect to a remote machine with

```
ssh -X user@remote.machine.net
```

the XQuartz application launches. When I type

```
xterm
```

into Terminal.app, an X11 terminal window (named xterm) opens. So far so good, but I like my Terminal.app configuration. Do I have to use the XQuartz terminal, or can I somehow redirect the xterm session to use Terminal.app?